# CellForItematIndexPath cannot set variable

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a variable in a UICollectionViewCell that I'm testing at the moment... here's my cellforitem

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: chatCellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
    c.userDidSend = (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) ? true : false
    return c
}
```

In the ChatCell class, I initialize the variable using `var userDidSend: Bool?`
, however whenever I test the variable, it always returns nil. Below is where the variable is being tested for each cell.

```
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    if userDidSend == true {
        setupSentChat()
    } else if userDidSend == false {
        setupRecievedChat()
    }

    print(userDidSend)
}
```

Asides from this particular issue, everything works fine.
Thoughts?

**EDIT:**
setupViews is called when the cell view is initialized.

```
override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}
```

Comment: Where are you testing the value of `userDidSend`? Perhaps you should show relevant code from your `ChatCell` class.

Comment: @rmaddy I have included it in an edit.

Comment: Where is this `setupViews` method? When is it called? Please provide context to your code. Please make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: So `setupViews()` is called BEFORE you set the value `userDidSend`, so why should it work? What about writing a custom setter on `userDidSend` with `didSet` that'd call `setupViews()`?

Comment: @Stefan Remember that cells get reused over and over so a cell needs to be written to handle both values of `userDidSend` and it needs to handle it be changed at any time.

Comment: @rmaddy I've solved the issue but I'm curious if my current method is viable. You mentioned having the cell being able to handle being changed at any time. Would my current solution present any problems should that be the case? Thanks.

Comment: On the surface your code looks fine but since you've posted no details about what the two "setup" methods do, there is no way to know. Just remember that both of those "setup" method can be called multiple times for a given cell instance. If your code handles that properly you should be fine. Make sure you are not adding subviews over and over each time one is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom setter seems to have solved the issue.

```
var userDidSend: Bool? {
    didSet {
        if userDidSend == true {
            setupSentChat()
        } else if userDidSend == false {
            setupRecievedChat()
        }
    }
}
```